# Automatically control spacing between paragraphs in a report class

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, report

The figure below shows first space (between paragraph one and two). And the manually added space between paragraph two and three.

My question: is it possible to automatically control the space between paragraphs. 
Following is my sample code.

[image]

My code:

```
    \documentclass{report}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \begin{document}

        \newcommand{\parbreak}{ \vspace{2.5em}}

    \chapter{Test Chapter}

    \lipsum[1]

    \lipsum[1]

    \parbreak % I want it to be spaced without adding this line explicitly 
    \lipsum[1]

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

space between paragraphs is determined by `\parskip`. in preamble change its default value with:

```
\setlength\parskip{2.5em}% it would be better define distance in ex (5ex) 
                         %  or in pt, pc, mm, etc (see edit below)
```

than you will obtain what you like to have:

[image]

complete *mwe*:

```
\documentclass{report}
\setlength\parskip{5ex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**edit:** as said [Barbara Beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) in her comment below: "`em` is a unit meant for horizontal distances is better use `ex`, which is intended for vertical distances and is relative to the current font (as is em)." and further: "both are defined with fonts size. consequently if they change, the distance will also change. so, it might be better to stick with a definitive physical unit like `pt`, `pc` or `mm`."

Comment: nice, you were quicker! ^^

Comment: the `em` is a unit meant for horizontal distances.  better would be `ex`, which is intended for vertical distances and is relative to the current font (as is `em`).  but if font size changes in the document are likely, it might be better to stick with a definitive physical unit like `pt`, `pc` or `mm`, to avoid differences when a type size change incorporates multiple paragraphs or occurs at paragraph breaks.

Comment: @Georges and made some spelling errors which i i now try to correct :-(.

Comment: I was trying to complete your answer, but I have not saved my changes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, yes, you have right. i overlooked this (actually in rush i read cm). corrected now to `ex`.

Comment: Thank you @Zarko. I am creating a new document class based on report class, in the maketitle i used the normal parskip but in the text i used the new one (2.5 ex). I was wondering what is the correct way to implement this. What i did was setting the length after \begin{document} and it worked. but i was wondering if this is correct way.

Comment: @Sari, people usual set `\parskip` globaly in preamble (in your case to `2.5ex`) and in exceptions as in title package change vertical distance manually for example with `\vspace{<length>}` between its lines.. on this way you have uniform layout of your document,